# Are the term **sample space** in Machine Learning and the one in probability theory the same?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, machine-learning

This [CMU Machine Learning Text Book](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf) gives this formula to apply Bayes' rule

[image]

> where $y_j$ denotes the jth possible value for Y, $x_k$ denotes the **kth possible vector value** for X.

I guess all of the **kth possible vector value** constitute the [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space). is my understanding right?

my concern is whether the term **sample space** in Machine Learning and the on in probability theory are the same?

it seems that Machine Learning articles rarely use the term **sample space**.